# Control application versions on registered MDM device from Google Android Management API

Tags: c#, android, google-play, mdm, android-management-api

Is there a way to control which version of a particular application from the play store should be installed on the fully managed device using Android Management API?

Example - Install Version 1.0, 2.0 based on what the Admin decides.

Can something be done with ApplicationPolicy and control the application versions, updates from the policy of the device?

```
{
  "packageName": string,
  "installType": enum(InstallType),
  "lockTaskAllowed": boolean,
  "defaultPermissionPolicy": enum(PermissionPolicy),
  "permissionGrants": [
    {
      object(PermissionGrant)
    }
  ],
  "managedConfiguration": {
    object
  },
  "disabled": boolean,
  "minimumVersionCode": number,
  "delegatedScopes": [
    enum(DelegatedScope)
  ],
  "managedConfigurationTemplate": {
    object(ManagedConfigurationTemplate)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I don't believe this is possible. I believe even for Android Management API it still obeys the rules of Google Play where the user is given the latest version.

--- edit
I've just thought of a hack which might make this possible. Eseentially you could give every version of the app a different package name in your build tool, then use admin based targeting to choose which package names are available. It's a bit of a hack, and I probably wouldn't recommend it, but it might be the only way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Nick, is it possible with EMM API? 
And also how about self hosting apk because few MDM solutions seem to have this functionality.

Comment: I'm not an expert but the docs are here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145182. I believe even with self-hosting the version code has to increase every time you do an update, and you can't do any admin specific targeting to users, because Google decides that based on the manifest, and "Self-hosted apps are published to the production channel only, and not to an alpha or beta channel."